# Row Address After Filtering

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a sheet with around 300k rows. I apply filtering based on dates. After filtering the sheet looks like as follows;

```
A1 - Header
A2 - Header
A243349 - First data
```

In order to copy&paste I would like to get A243349 as the address. I tried the code below, it founds correct row, however it gives "First Data" not "A243349"

```
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim FirstFilteredRow As Range
With Sheets("MySheet")
    Set DataRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With
Set FirstFilteredRow = DataRange.Offset(2, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Rows(1)
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [Range.Address property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) to retrieve the address of the cell

```
Debug.Print FirstFilteredRow.Address
```